# Pandas dates being wrongly plotted at start of month

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a timeseries in Pandas where the dates are at the end of the month:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series({
    '2018-04-30':     0,
    '2018-05-31':     1,
    '2018-06-30':     0,
    '2018-07-31':    1,
    '2018-08-31':    0,
    '2018-09-30':    1,
})
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)
```

When I plot this with matplotlib I get the result I'd expect, with points at the end-of-month and the line starting just before May 2018:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(s)
```

[image: Matplotlib graph]

But Pandas' native plot function plots the points at the start of the month:

```
s.plot()
```

[image: Pandas graph]

I thought perhaps this was just Pandas labelling '30 April' as 'April', but that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
s2 = pd.Series([0.2, 0.7], index=pd.date_range('2018-05-01', '2018-05-02'))
s.plot()
s2.plot()
```

[image: Pandas plot with first-of-month also plotted]

Is this a bug in Pandas or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in pandas. To get the same as with matplotlib you may always use `x_compat=True`. This then would also allow to use `matplotlib.dates` formatters and locators.

```
s = pandas.Series(...)
s.plot(x_compat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've filed a bug report https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20688